# Add date to string but getting: The data types varchar(max) and date are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a column `date_of_creation` saved as `varchar` in table.I am trying to fetch records between the dates by converting the `date_of_creation` field to date.

```
   SET @WhereQuery = @WhereQuery + ' AND CONVERT(Date,tbl.date_of_creation,103) BETWEEN ''' +CONVERT(date,ISNULL(@DateFrom,'1/1/1753'),101) + ''' + AND ''' +CONVERT(date,ISNULL(@DateTo, GETDATE()),101)+ ''''   
    
   PRINT @WhereClause
```

I am getting below error

> The data types varchar(max) and date are incompatible in the add operator.

I know I am getting this error because I am trying to concatenate a DATE type with a string `@WhereClause`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had your quotes in the wrong place and `@WhereClause` != `@WhereQuery`.

```
DECLARE @WhereQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @DateFrom VARCHAR(12), @DateTo VARCHAR(21);

SET @WhereQuery = @WhereQuery
    + ' AND CONVERT(Date,tbl.date_of_creation,103)'
    + ' BETWEEN CONVERT(date,''' + ISNULL(@DateFrom,'1/1/1753') + ''',101)
    AND CONVERT(date,''' + ISNULL(@DateTo, CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),GETDATE(),101)) + ''',101)';

PRINT @WhereQuery;
```

Note it seems odd that you are using British format (103) against your table column and US format (101) against your variable. I would have expected them to be consistent. You do need to ensure you use the correct formats for the data you are using.

For my testing I used:

```
SET @WhereQuery = @WhereQuery
    + ' AND CONVERT(Date,tbl.date_of_creation,103)'
    + ' BETWEEN CONVERT(date,''' + ISNULL(@DateFrom,'1/1/1753') + ''',103)
    AND CONVERT(date,''' + ISNULL(@DateTo, CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),GETDATE(),103)) + ''',103)';
```

Also I would highly suggest converting `date_of_creation` to the proper `datetime` datetype. Using strings to store datetime values is asking for trouble.

Comment: now getting Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Did you read my second to last comment of the answer? You're mixing up your date formats, and I don't know what you are really using to be able to correct it. It *might* work if you change all the formats to 103.

Comment: I used same sql you mentioned without any changes

Comment: Well yes, but I used the same SQL as you... as I don't have access to your table and variable values I could only test it as provided. It works if your dates are in the formats you are expecting, but not otherwise. Try 103.